# how to read pdf file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to read pdf file in iphone/ipad and i want to give animation(turn page) effect each page of pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just regular viewing u can use UIWebView. Once you have created this object assign it an IBOutlet and do something like this:

```
[mywebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResources:@"myPDF" ofType:@"pdf"]]]];
```

To embed page flip features you can Subclass UIWebView and and start playing around.